# When will the sequence $x_i = g^{x_{i-1}} \mod p$, $p$ prime, repeat?

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assume the following sequence:
$$x_i = g^{x_{i-1}} \mod p$$
where $p$ prime, $g$ is a generator of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (sequence starts with $x_1$). I want to know for which $i$, does the sequence start to repeat? I assume that somehow depends on the order of $g$ (which is $p-1$, correct?) but I could not figure out in which way exactly, since I worked through a few examples and it seems to be lower than the order of $g$.

How would I go about solving this problem?

**Edit**

It was pointed to me in the comments that the sequence might repeat if it "returns" to a previous value. I amended the question.

Comment: The sequence might repeat by going back to a previous value, not necessarily $x_1$.

Comment: Can you share the data you have?

Comment: Sure. Consider $p=11$,$g=2$,$x_1=5$. Then the sequence is:
$5$;$2^5 \mod 11 = 10$;$1$;$2$;$4$;$5$

Comment: Is that *all* the data you have? I suggest you gather more data.

Comment: Here is some data for your: https://pastebin.com/3HyraXA5 . There does not seem to have an obvious pattern to the orbits. But they all come back to $x_1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660454/euler-phi-function-and-power-sequence